# How to implement staggered grid view with SLIVERS in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, staggered-gridview, customscrollview

I want to implement a **Staggered GridView**, because my SliverGrid delegate requires an **aspect ratio**, and I want the grid items to be **dynamically sized**  which is only possible with staggered gridview as far as I know.

My question is how can I implement a staggered gridview and use it in my **CustomScrollView** as a **sliver**?

---

Edit:

My **pubspec.yaml** file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.5.1
  ...other packages
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Update version wrap `GridView` with `SliverToBoxAdapter` and set gridView `physics` to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` because `CustomScrollView` will handle scroll event.

```dart
SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: GridView.custom(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

**Test Widget**

```dart
Scaffold(
          body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          const SliverAppBar(
            title: Text("title"),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: GridView.custom(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              gridDelegate: SliverQuiltedGridDelegate(
                crossAxisCount: 4,
                mainAxisSpacing: 4,
                crossAxisSpacing: 4,
                repeatPattern: QuiltedGridRepeatPattern.inverted,
                pattern: const [
                  QuiltedGridTile(2, 2),
                  QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
                  QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
                  QuiltedGridTile(1, 2),
                ],
              ),
              childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) => Container(
                  color: Colors.cyanAccent,
                  child: Text("$index"),
                ),
                childCount: 44,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )),
```

**`flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.1`** provides `SliverStaggeredGrid` to use as `sliver`'s child.

```dart
 CustomScrollView(
   slivers: [
     SliverStaggeredGrid.countBuilder(...
```

Comment: The documentatin specifies that: "This layout is intended for a small number of items. I didn't find, for the moment, a performant algorithm which would work in a Sliver context, that's why this is not a GridView and therefore there are no SliverStaggeredGrid."

Comment: Did you try `SliverStaggeredGrid.countBuilder` to archive your UI?

Comment: Yes I did try and I had no SliverStaggeredGrid class, however I added flutter_staggered_grid_view  to my pubspec.yaml file, ran pub get, and imported the package.

Comment: Seems it has been removed on `v0.5.1` you can switch to `0.4.1`, I will try different approach with current version.

Answer (score 4):

Big Mistake never use shrinkWrap(when you have alot of items) in your list(performance issues).

2022 Update version
flutter staggered has updated itself and removed SliverStaggeredGrid
in the new version, you can use QuiltedGridDelegate.
like this:

```
      CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverGrid(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) => Container(
                color: Colors.cyanAccent,
                child: Text("$index"),
              ),
              childCount: 44,
            ),
            gridDelegate: SliverQuiltedGridDelegate(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              mainAxisSpacing: 4,
              crossAxisSpacing: 4,
              repeatPattern: QuiltedGridRepeatPattern.inverted,
              pattern: const [
                QuiltedGridTile(2, 1),
                QuiltedGridTile(2, 2),
                QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
                QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
                QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
              ],
            ))
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Dene());
  }
}

class Dene extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                mainAxisSpacing: 16,
                crossAxisSpacing: 16,
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                itemCount: 22,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    width: 200,
                    height: 100,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  );
                },
                staggeredTileBuilder: (index) {
                  return StaggeredTile.fit(1);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

void main() => runApp(Dene());

class Dene extends StatelessWidget {
  const Dene({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                crossAxisCount: 4,
                itemCount: 22,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => new Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: new Center(
                      child: new CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        child: new Text('$index'),
                      ),
                    )),
                staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
                    new StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2 : 1),
                mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```